# Is the post ID unique across all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, posts

The URL of any post on any Stack Exchange site (Webmasters, Stack Overflow, Photography and so on...) has the following format:

`http://site_name.stackexchange.com/questions/questionID/question_short_description`

So I wonder: is the question ID unique for ALL sites?

Comment: Did you open up a browser and try? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13 http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13/

Comment: @random I did. The link I tried did not worked. But wouldn't judge the role by one (or any reasonable quantity) try.

Comment: Why downvoted? Nice question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the post ID in the link is not a unique ID for all posts on Stack Exchange. The post ID in the link is only unique per-site.