# Changing the site from a full URL redirects to a valid page

Tags: support, hyperlinks

While I was viewing [this post](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/20774/why-do-trees-break-at-the-same-wind-speed), I wanted to redirect to [the skeptics site](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour), so I changed the `earthscience` part of the URL to skeptics. This took me to [this post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14375/do-fingerprint-scanners-cause-skin-cancer/20774#20774). Is there an explanation behind this?

Comment: Its called the post ID. Apparently there is an answer on skeptics with the same ID as the question on earthscience

Comment: Is the number after the /questions part the post id? Because the first is questions/20774 and the other is questions/360703

Comment: The first number is the question ID. In your second link you see the same number in the end. Therefore it is an Answer there. Questions and Answers are basically both just Posts, and have a Post ID.

Comment: Also see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239687/is-the-post-id-unique-across-all-stack-exchange-sites

Answer (score 9):

That's an interesting one.

When you browse to `/questions/[id]`, it will look for a question with that ID. If such question is not found, **it will look for answer having that ID**, and if found, will show the parent question and put focus on the answer.

That's what happened in your case, and the interesting part is, that the answer is deleted. That's why we can't see it, as we don't have enough reputation on the site.

All in all, when you want to manually give link to a site, it's better to strip everything from the URL, otherwise you'll just end up at random question or a 404 Not Found error page.

I will also support a feature request asking to throw the Not Found in case such as this one, but that should be posted separately.

Comment: Or better yet, just use the site switcher at the right hand side of the site. Press the SE logo, and you can search for sites in the network there.

Comment: @Luuklag takes more time than manually changing the URL. :-)

Comment: Depends, you would have to type less characters to find the site, and not select any part to be overwritten.

Comment: Technically it looks for a row with that id in the Posts table. Based on what the PostTypeId is it does a proper redirect. Try it here:  https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1370590